# Как обработать нажатия этих кнопок?

Tags: android, toolbar

Самих этих кнопок, а не пунктов меню. Какой у них id в системе? Например кнопку назад можно поймать как andriod.R.id.home...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582075/cannot-catch-toolbar-home-button-click-event

Answer (score 0):

Какие вы id создадите для элементов, так их и поймаете. Для левого меню у вас должен быть NavigationView с пунктами меню из drawer_menu:
Разметка XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navview"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    android:background="@color/drawerBackground"
    />
```

Код:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.itemMenu1:
                        // some
                        break;
                    case R.id.menuitem_itemMenu2:
                        // some
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

});

Для правого меню:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.item1:
           //some
           return true;
   }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужен обработчик клика по тем кнопкам что отмечены на картинке стрелочками, а не пунктов меню.  В общем у меня есть кнопка fab по нажатию на которую всплывают еще две, и я хочу скрывать их по совершению любого действия не связанного с нажатием на эти кнопки. Может существует какое либо иное решение?

Comment: Дело в том, что обработчики можно уже вешать, а при чем тут fab-кнопки?

Comment: Куда вешать? Обработчик onOptionsItemSelected и onNavigationItemSelected срабатывает по клику на пункт меню. Мне нужно обработать кнопку открытия этого меню и кнопку открытия NavigationView.   Я пробовал вешать OnClickListener на navview, но он не работает

Comment: На любую кнопку вешается SetOnClickListener, и обрабатывает нажатия на кнопки, на вашем рисунке это нажатия на меню.

Comment: Ну и как мне определить эту кнопку меню? У меня ее нет в layout. И соответственно у нее нет id. Также как и нет в лэйауте кнопки NavigationDrawer.